# Why tabs belong to “search” section rather than to “content” section in Google?

Tags: tabs

What is the rationale behind keeping tabs visually connected with the search section rather with the results here? I've also seen this pattern in accordions.

[image]

I would understand if selected options would have same background as results, visually reinforcing connection between the two. But in this case it just an underline.

So it's interesting why would one want to keep tabs visually connected to search rather than to the content.

Answer (score 2):

Edited after Tin Mans comment.

**Because that aren’t tabs.** Ok maybe they are but they are filters for categories in the first place. Google visually hints that you can use them like tabs by adding the blue line. This communicates the concept of tabs but emphasises the dependency on the search. If it were more like standard tabs however, with a white background for the active one, it would look like the content is predefined and doesn’t (necessarily) depend on the search.

Comment: Tabs and filters aren't mutually exclusive. Tabs are a UI element, filters are a UX pattern that can be implemented using tabs, drop-down menus, checkboxes, or other UI elements. The screenshot in the question shows filters presented as tabs.

Comment: @TinMan, Tabs aren’t elements but are patterns too. The categories look like tabs, but not in the way people expect them to. It is a way to make clear that the content is not connected to a static tab but part of the search.

Comment: I beg to differ. One way to test the difference between patterns and UI elements is to ask whether the pattern can be implemented using different UI elements. Can a "tabs" pattern be implemented using something other than tabs? Is a menu an implementation? What are the UI elements in the screenshot called, then, if not tabs?

Comment: Also, it's telling that the HIGs that I know (Material design, Microsoft's UWP HIG, the GNOME HIG, among others) all list tabs as UI components. I haven't seen a HIG that lists tabs under patterns.

Comment: @TinMan, I see the misunderstanding. It had to be “tabs aren’t just elements ...”. Every UI element is a pattern in some way because they try to communicate a concept to a user. The way they are designed can however make a huge difference in what people expect from these elements. It’s the expectation that the HIG’s you mention try to ensure/protect. So even if the concept of the tabs is the same, Google might have chosen this design because they wanted to ensure a certain expectation other than when the active tab had a white background.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question let's take an example:

Let's say I search the work "Key" I get the following results:

Inside **All**: [image]

Inside **News**:
[image]

Also, If you notice something. Inside **ALL**, the stats are:
[image]

And inside **NEWS**, the stats are 
[image]

So what do we infer is that the content is being segregated into different categories which are related to the search keyword which is "KEY" here.

Thus, it makes sense that the categories are visually connected to the searched keyword since they belong to that rather than the content itself. It's like saying, **Show me all the news article related to "StackOverflow"** or **Search everything on "StackOverflow"**.

I understand your argument that it is the content which is being classified but this only makes half the statement. 
The content is being classified for the keyword which you have searched. So I guess it makes sense to make it that way.

I hope I was able to give some idea on why it could be this way. Not saying this is right but just how I saw that when I thought of it.

I really like this question because this is something really minute and skips the eye out easily.

Thanks for asking! Helps us all to learn.

I hope I was able to help.

Keep exploring!

Answer (score 0):

The separation of the tabs from the content is there primarily to separate "static" elements (things that stay the same on all pages) from "dynamic" elements (things that change between pages).

It's just taking spacial cues from the real world and bringing them to the digital world. Imagine a notebook with tabs or a Rolodex. The tabs are all positioned lower than the current page, with the exception of the current tab. This indicates that there is content you can't see when you switch over to a different tab, overlaid by the content you're viewing now.

The same metaphor applies here. Switching to a different tab brings forward content that overlays content from other tabs.

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems like; 
Search + Filter selection are functions you perform, and below on another background is the result only.